# PHP - Intercept POST requests

Tags: php, request, http-post, intercept

I was wondering if anyone could help me solve how to view `$_POST` requests.

What i want to do, is check all `$_POST` requests, not just certain ones like `$_POST['name'], $_POST['post']` etc, I'd like to check every post, without being able to know the name of each POST request.

Here is what i've tried (snippet):

```
foreach ($_POST as $pst)
{
    echo $pst;
}
//And tried the above for GET too. (but the GET I've manged to working.)
```

I've also tried many others, that i can think off an can come to no resolution...

Comment: This should work fine. What is the result you get? Are you sure you are actually POSTing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You used the right solution

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){
    //> do your operation here
    echo $key.': '.$value;
}
```

You can use `$key` to get the param name

Comment: Thank you very much, that solution worked for me and i was able to tweak that to my needs.

Answer (score 2):

If you're just looking to output the posts so you can see them to troubleshoot something then i'd use something like this:

```
<?php
    echo "<pre>\n";
    print_r($_POST);
    echo "</pre>\n";
    exit;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Dan, I should of made my post clearer, but i'd like to analyze the post content. 

Example:
if($_POST == "hello world")...Without knowing the POST request's name